# using grep (awk?) how to find only the lines that have three single digits in it, between can be words or numbers

Tags: regex, awk

using grep (awk?) how to find only the lines that have three single digits 
in it,between the digits can be numbers or words.

```
 A) word 67,5 9 word 7,9 word word 7 word 91
 B) word 7 word 8 word 77,5 word word 5 word 55,6 word 1
 C) word word word 4 word 66,8 word 5 word word 1
```

so it finds only line C) because three digits here: 4  5  1

`grep -n '[[:blank:]][0-9][[:blank:]]` finds all three lines, also not the digit 1 in line C

Comment: What if the line contained 4 single digits - should that be printed too since it contains 3 single digits? In terms of allowed constituent characters - what is your definition of a "word"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This MAY be what you're looking for:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/(^| )[0-9]( |$)/,"&") == 3' file
 C) word word word 4 word 66,8 word 5 word word 1
```

or more robustly:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/(^|[[:blank:]])[[:digit:]]([[:blank:]]|$)/,"&") == 3' file
 C) word word word 4 word 66,8 word 5 word word 1
```